# Есть ли разница между ответами 200 и 200 OK retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Давно пользуюсь библиотекой retrofit, и всегда делал проверку на удачный запрос таким образом:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
...
}
```

при том что ответ приходил такой:  `200 https://...`. А теперь мне пришел такой ответ:

```
200 OK https://
```

вроде бы особой разницы нет, но я не могу поймать удачный ответ стандартным способом. Почему такая разница между ответами при наличии двух букв, и как можно отловить удачный ответ если есть статус OK?

### UPDATE:

Вот кусок кода где у меня проблемы:

```
mAPIService.getData("Bearer " + acc_token).enqueue(new Callback<UserInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<UserInfo> call, @NonNull Response<UserInfo> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    JsonObject photo_data = response.body().getPhoto_Data();

                    if (photo_data.get("exists").getAsBoolean()) {
                        mAPIService.getphoto("Bearer " + acc_token).enqueue(new Callback<GetPhoto>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetPhoto> call, @NonNull Response<GetPhoto> response) {
                                Log.i("m", String.valueOf(response.code()));

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<GetPhoto> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                            }
                        });
                    }


                } else {



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<UserInfo> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

первый запрос в если удачен, отправляет второй запрос ответ на который я не могу обработать, строка: `Log.i("m", String.valueOf(response.code()));` ничего не выводит.

### UPDATE_2:

Может проблема в том что в этом ответе нету тела:

```
<-- END HTTP (binary 2529251-byte body omitted)
```

Comment: Откуда вы берёте строки `200 https://...` и `200 OK https://`? В протоколе HTTP ничего подобного нет.

Comment: @andreymal, с логов, а что такое?

Comment: А то, что `isSuccessful` проверяет значение `code` из okhttp-объекта Response, которое там число, а не строка. И какой-нибудь `OK` в этом числе никак находиться не может. // Что означает фраза «не могу поймать удачный ответ стандартным способом»? Какую-то ошибку выбивает или в чём проблема?

Comment: @andreymal, проблема в том что мне пришел ответ где к числу 200 у меня прилепилось слово ok, и у меня не получается проверкой `isSuccessful` узнать удачный ли запрос или нет, ошибки нет, в логах у меня запрос удачный, но я не могу этого узнать проверкой.

Comment: @andreymal, хм.... вот смотрите какая ситуация, раньше мне приходил ответ 200 и я проверяя результат запроса програмно а не в логах условием `isSuccessful` мог узнать могу ли я начать извлекать данные из ответа, или же мне сервер вернул какую-то ошибку, а теперь я не могу используя вышеприведенное условие узнать могу ли я извлекать данные из ответа или нет, значение code() я проверял, тоже глухо, я хочу например при удачном ответе вывести лог, а я не могу этого сделать потому что не могу узнать удачный запрос или нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92142/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог решить проблему заменой класса модели. В чем суть вообще - я с сервера пытаюсь скачать картинку, и по стандарту в интерфейсе писал класс модель который был пустым, метод проб и ошибок я понял что ретрофит мне возвращает ошибку о том что я использую не тот тип данных, например такую ошибку я получил:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

дальше я пошел дальше гуглить, и понял что мне нужно скачать файл а не распарсить ответ, а значит в интерфейсе нужно заменить класс модель на `ResponseBody`, в итоге выглядит так:

```
Call<ResponseBody> getphoto (@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

и вот что у меня есть в классе:

```
apiService().getphoto("Bearer " + acc_token).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
          if (response.isSuccessful()) {
             Log.i("m", "+");
          }
     }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

         }
  });
```

и как ни странно я смог получить нужный мне результат. Может кому поможет :)